# If statement involving this.indexof in order to animate an element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked many of other questions involving issues like this, but none have helped.
I'm very new to this so bare with my obvious lack of knowledge.

I was trying to create a navigation where once `mouseenter` on the navigation link itself, the nav link will be animated to rise up by `5px` and a box of the same width would drop down to meet it in the middle. I can think of a way to do it but it will involve a lot more code than if i could use an if statement instead.

```
<div id="header" class="wrapper">
    <div id="header_logo" class="header"></div> 
    <div id="header_main" class="header"> 
        <div id="nav_drop_btn">
            <div id="nav_drop_box">
                <span id="1" class="nav_drop"></span>
                <span id="2" class="nav_drop"></span>
                <span id="3" class="nav_drop"></span>
                <span id="4" class="nav_drop"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="nav_btn">Home</span>
            <span class="nav_btn">About</span>
            <span class="nav_btn">Contact</span>
            <span class="nav_btn">Portfolio</span>
        </div>

$(".nav_btn").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"25px",bottom:"0px"},400);
    if (this.indexOf("home") >=-1){$("#1").animate({height:"50px"})};
});
```

`.nav_btn` is the class for all of the navigation links. `home` is the navigation button in question.

I am pretty sure i have done this all wrong. so would very much appreciate if someone could help me to understand what is wrong with the If statement. the rest of my code works its just this.

`home` is text within the `<span>` for `.nav_id`, im trying to distinguish between which `.nav_btn` has been clicked to then activate another line of code to animate the corresponding top bar which comes down to meet it, this top bar containing an image for that particular navigation link

Comment: Can you please post some of the html you're using for this?

Comment: its pretty messy but here ya go:
`<div id="header" class="wrapper">  
 <div id="header_logo" class="header"></div>  
 <div id="header_main" class="header">  
 <div id="nav_drop_btn">  
 <div id="nav_drop_box">  
 <span id="1" class="nav_drop"></span>  
 <span id="2" class="nav_drop"></span>  
 <span id="3" class="nav_drop"></span>  
 <span id="4" class="nav_drop"></span>  
 </div>  
 <span class="nav_btn">Home</span>  
 <span class="nav_btn">About</span>             <span class="nav_btn">Contact</span>  
<span class="nav_btn">Portfolio</span>  
</div>`

Comment: sorry. accidently sent it too soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` does not represent a string value. If you're looking for a value to search with `indexOf`, and it's a link, you'll probably want to use `this.href.indexOf` instead.

```
<a href="/home/">Test</a>
<a href="/nothome/">Test 2</a>

$('a').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log(this.href.indexOf('/home'));
    if (this.href.indexOf('/home') !== -1) {
        console.log('Mouse enter home');    
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwPm6/

And you can use jQuery's `.text()` if you want to search the link's visible text node value:

```
<a href="/home/">Test</a>
<a href="/nothome/">Other</a>

$('a').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log($(this).text().indexOf('Test'));
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('Test') !== -1) {
        console.log('Mouse enter home');   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJCp8/

And with `SPAN`'s:

```
<span>Test</span>
<span>Other</span>

$('span').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log($(this).text().indexOf('Test'));
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('Test') !== -1) {
        console.log('Mouse enter home');    
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJCp8/1/

And as the other answer from N.G. suggests, you need to test for something NOT equal to -1, and additionally you might consider using `.toLowerCase().indexOf('home')` to normalize the string test value and search value casing.

To wit, just looking at your code and making these adjustments, I come up with this:

```
$(".nav_btn").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"25px",bottom:"0px"},400);
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("home") !== -1){
        $("#1").animate({height:"50px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: its not a link, the actual value "home" that im trying to find is text within the .nav_btn. because i have 4 nav_btns, but they are actually just text with a span with a class=".nav_btn" in them

Comment: See the second example using `.text()`.

Comment: thanks for being so patient with me, i rather slow atm.
I have changes it back to '!== -1' i have added '.text' and have attempted it with the <span> example you posted. i just cant get it going.

Comment: yes thank you, that last block works :D i guess it was the .toLowerase. thanks so much, you've been a massive help

Comment: It's usually really helpful to normalize a string case before a comparison, that way it doesn't depend on the case on value and search/comparison. It's a good habit to get into, just be aware of when you shouldn't do it (for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is not the correct function to use for this. You could give the home button a special class/id to allow it to behave differently on mouseenter.

```
$(".nav_btn").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"25px",bottom:"0px"},400);
});

$("#home").mouseenter(function() { 
    $(this).animate({height:"50px"});
});
```

Comment: the other element that is being animated is "#1", home is just the text i am searching for within the .nav_btn so that the JS can know which one of the top bars to bring down to meet which .nav_btn

Answer (score 0):

Your `indexOf` is checking against >= -1

This will always be true. -1 is the value returned if the search string is not found.

Perhaps you mean to check: `if (this.indexOf("home") > -1)`
instead?

Comment: This is because i was trying to make it always be true to see if it would execute the code or not. unfortunately it didn't. thankyou for commenting though.